# Formatting output text to .doc/.docx

Tags: c++, ms-word, format

I searched how to formatting text to .doc/.docx file for weeks , but i don't found any good solution.

So my question is:

How to formatting text to output .doc/.docx file? (bold, center etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is poorly formatted, I will do my best to help out.

Microsoft has a [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776) on using Microsoft Office formatting in C++. It looks like a pretty tough process.

The file you are concerned with is :

> Word 2002   | msword.olb

Here is a [codeguru link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/tutorials/article.php/c14519/Microsoft-Word-Automation-Class.htm) that attempts to address your issue, it might be somewhat out of date. It allows you to

> CreateBlankDocument()
> AppendText(CString szText)
> GetLine(int nLine)
>
> OpenWordFile(CString szFileName)
>
> SaveWordFileAs(CString szFileName)

Okay : this [Microsoft Word Automation post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238393/en-us) teaches you full functionality in automating a word document. My apologies for the wall of text to follow.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ole2.h>

// 
// AutoWrap() - Automation helper function...
// 
HRESULT AutoWrap(int autoType, VARIANT *pvResult, IDispatch *pDisp, 
      LPOLESTR ptName, int cArgs...) 
{
      // Begin variable-argument list...
      va_list marker;
      va_start(marker, cArgs);

      if(!pDisp) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "NULL IDispatch passed to AutoWrap()", 
                       "Error", 0x10010);
            _exit(0);
      }

      // Variables used...
      DISPPARAMS dp = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
      DISPID dispidNamed = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
      DISPID dispID;
      HRESULT hr;
      char buf[200];
      char szName[200];
   
      // Convert down to ANSI
      WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ptName, -1, szName, 256, NULL, NULL);
   
      // Get DISPID for name passed...
      hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &ptName, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
                                &dispID);
      if(FAILED(hr)) {
            sprintf(buf, 
                    "IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames(\"%s\") failed w/err0x%08lx",
                    szName, hr);
            MessageBox(NULL, buf, "AutoWrap()", 0x10010);
            _exit(0);
            return hr;
      }
   
      // Allocate memory for arguments...
      VARIANT *pArgs = new VARIANT[cArgs+1];

      // Extract arguments...
      for(int i=0; i<cArgs; i++) {
            pArgs[i] = va_arg(marker, VARIANT);
      }
   
      // Build DISPPARAMS
      dp.cArgs = cArgs;
      dp.rgvarg = pArgs;
   
      // Handle special-case for property-puts!
      if(autoType & DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) {
            dp.cNamedArgs = 1;
            dp.rgdispidNamedArgs = &dispidNamed;
      }
   
      // Make the call!
      hr = pDisp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, autoType, 
                         &dp, pvResult, NULL, NULL);
      if(FAILED(hr)) {
            sprintf(buf,
                    "IDispatch::Invoke(\"%s\"=%08lx) failed w/err 0x%08lx", 
                    szName, dispID, hr);
            MessageBox(NULL, buf, "AutoWrap()", 0x10010);
            _exit(0);
            return hr;
      }
      // End variable-argument section...
      va_end(marker);
   
      delete [] pArgs;
   
      return hr;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
      // Initialize COM for this thread...
      CoInitialize(NULL);

      // Get CLSID for Word.Application...
      CLSID clsid;
      HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);
      if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ::MessageBox(NULL, "CLSIDFromProgID() failed", "Error", 
                         0x10010);
            return -1;
      }

      // Start Word and get IDispatch...
      IDispatch *pWordApp;
      hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
                            IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pWordApp);
      if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ::MessageBox(NULL, "Word not registered properly", 
                         "Error", 0x10010);
            return -2;
      }

      // Make Word visible
      {
            VARIANT x;
            x.vt = VT_I4;
            x.lVal = 1;
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pWordApp, L"Visible", 1, 
                     x);
      }

      // Get Documents collection
      IDispatch *pDocs;
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pWordApp, L"Documents", 
                     0);

            pDocs = result.pdispVal;
      }

      // Call Documents.Open() to open C:\Doc1.doc
      IDispatch *pDoc;
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            VARIANT x;
            x.vt = VT_BSTR;
            x.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"C:\\Doc1.doc");

            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pDocs, L"Open", 1, x);
            pDoc = result.pdispVal;
            SysFreeString(x.bstrVal);
      }

      // Get BuiltinDocumentProperties collection
      IDispatch *pProps;
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pDoc, 
                     L"BuiltinDocumentProperties", 0);
            pProps = result.pdispVal;
      }

      // Get "Subject" from BuiltInDocumentProperties.Item("Subject")
      IDispatch *pPropSubject;
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            VARIANT x;
            x.vt = VT_BSTR;
            x.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"Subject");
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pProps, L"Item", 1, x);
            pPropSubject = result.pdispVal;
            SysFreeString(x.bstrVal);
      }

      // Get the Value of the Subject property and display it
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pPropSubject, L"Value",
                     0);
            char buf[512];
            wcstombs(buf, result.bstrVal, 512);
            ::MessageBox(NULL, buf, "Subject", 0x10000);
         
      }

      // Set the Value of the Subject DocumentProperty
      {
            VARIANT x;
            x.vt = VT_BSTR;
            x.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"This is my subject");
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pPropSubject, L"Value", 1, 
                     x);
            ::MessageBox(NULL, 
                         "Subject property changed, examine document.",
                         "Subject", 0x10000);
            SysFreeString(x.bstrVal);
      }

      // Get CustomDocumentProperties collection
      IDispatch *pCustomProps;
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pDoc, 
                     L"CustomDocumentProperties", 0);
            pCustomProps = result.pdispVal;
      }

      // Add a new property named "CurrentYear"
      {     
            VARIANT parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4;
            parm1.vt = VT_BSTR;
            parm1.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"CurrentYear");
            parm2.vt = VT_BOOL;
            parm2.boolVal = false;
            parm3.vt = VT_I4;
            parm3.lVal = 1; //msoPropertyTypeNumber = 1
            parm4.vt = VT_I4;
            parm4.lVal = 1999;

            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pCustomProps, L"Add", 4, parm4,
                     parm3, parm2, parm1);
            ::MessageBox(NULL, "Custom property added, examine document.",
                         "Custom Property", 0x10000);
            SysFreeString(parm1.bstrVal);
      }

      // Get the custom property "CurrentYear" and delete it
      IDispatch *pCustomProp;
      {
            VARIANT result;
            VariantInit(&result);
            VARIANT x;
            x.vt = VT_BSTR;
            x.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"CurrentYear");
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pCustomProps, L"Item",
                     1, x);
            pCustomProp = result.pdispVal;
            SysFreeString(x.bstrVal);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pCustomProp, L"Delete", 0);
            ::MessageBox(NULL,
                         "Custom property removed, examine document.",
                         "Custom Property", 0x10000);
      }
      
      // Close the document without saving changes and quit Word
      {
            VARIANT x;
            x.vt = VT_BOOL;
            x.boolVal = false;
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pDoc, L"Close", 1, x);
            AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pWordApp, L"Quit", 0);
      }

      // Cleanup
      pCustomProp->Release();
      pCustomProps->Release();
      pPropSubject->Release();
      pProps->Release();
      pDoc->Release();
      pDocs->Release();
      pWordApp->Release();


      // Uninitialize COM for this thread...
      CoUninitialize();

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you give any sample program in .cpp? I'm newbie with outputs etc. and need  help. Of course i thanking for your answer :)

Comment: To be fair I'm trying to find the relevant code for you. They have multiple examples of printing docs and extracting information, I'll be editing my post in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solution is to use libOPC. [Documentation](http://libopc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Samples&referringTitle=Documentation) shows the simple examples(not so simple). Its cross-platform solution.

One of the simplest example

```
#include <opc/opc.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    opcInitLibrary();
    opcContainer *c=opcContainerOpen(_X("sample.opc"), OPC_OPEN_READ_WRITE, NULL, NULL); 
    opcPart part1=opcPartCreate(c, _X("part1.xml"), _X("text/plain"), 0); 
    opcPart part2=opcPartCreate(c, _X("part2.xml"), _X("text/plain"), 0); 

    opcContainerOutputStream *stream1=opcContainerCreateOutputStream(c, part1); 
    opcContainerOutputStream *stream2=opcContainerCreateOutputStream(c, part2); 

    // WRITE to stream1 and stream2 concurrently using
    opcContainerWriteOutputStream(stream1, "HELLO", 5);
    opcContainerWriteOutputStream(stream2, "HELLO", 5);
    opcContainerWriteOutputStream(stream2, " WORLD", 6);
    opcContainerWriteOutputStream(stream1, " WORLD", 6);

    opcContainerCloseOutputStream(stream1); 
    opcContainerCloseOutputStream(stream2); 
    opcContainerClose(c, OPC_CLOSE_NOW);
    opcFreeLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read or write <kbd>.docx</kbd> files you will want to familiarize yourself with the EMCA-376 Standard for Office Open XML format documents. You can find a collection of these documents (various editions) on the [EMCA website](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a library, or to do Word automation.

Word's internal format is quite complex, and you don't want to try to do this directly.